# Salesforce.com finding a user ID from authentication token

Tags: web-services, salesforce, apex-code

I am implementing a method that receive an authentication token from a user. Based on that token, how can I get the ID of the user that owns the token? The method is being called by an iPhone application. Here is the method declarartion:

```
global static void getItems(String authToken)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to call the REST api's discovery service @superfell provided a great answer that should allow you to solve your problem:

[How to tell if instance specfic Salesforce URL is from Sandbox or Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146286/how-to-tell-if-instance-specfic-salesforce-url-is-from-sandbox-or-production)